# Understanding Loudness & Broadcast Standards

Tags: levels, loudness, broadcasting

This is going to be pretty broad cause this stuff just confuses me so I wondering, if you guy's could give me some resources to check out so I can understand them a little better. I don't even know how to ask a question so I'll just list it out what I'd like to learn haha:

- LKFS
- Leq
- Weighting Filters
- Dialnorm
- Intersample Peaks

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Busy day for me right now, but I'll point you to a blog post I did a little while ago that covers some of the basic of loudness metering: http://www.dynamicinterference.com/blog/2012/04/what-the-hell-do-all-these-letters-and-numbers-mean/

It'll get you started at least.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go hardcore...

http://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BS.1770/en

This is the spec that most North American Broadcasters adhere to when measuring.

http://www.atsc.org/cms/index.php/standards/recommended-practices/185-a85-techniques-for-establishing-and-maintaining-audio-loudness-for-digital-television

ATSC's guidelines

Answer (score 1):

This is a great video explaining intersample peaks.  While they are talking about the metering in Final Cut, the information is still great.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQTxSyK-ATI

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

http://tech.ebu.ch/docs/r/r128.pdf

Some useful and enjoyable reading regarding "Loudness normalisation and permitted maximum level of audio signals"

At the bottom of the document there are a list of references for further reading.

[1]  EBU Tech Doc 3205-E ‘The EBU standard peak-programme meter for the control of 
international transmissions’

[2]  ITU-R BS.645 ‘Test signals and metering to be used on international sound programme 
connections’

[3]  ITU-R BS.1770 ‘Algorithms to measure audio programme loudness and true-peak audio 
level’

[4]  EBU Tech Doc 3341 ‘Loudness Metering: ‘EBU Mode’ metering to supplement loudness 
normalisation in accordance with EBU R 128’

[5]  EBU Tech Doc 3342 ‘Loudness Range: A measure to supplement loudness normalisation in 
accordance with EBU R 128’

[6]  EBU Tech Doc 3343 ‘Practical Guidelines for Production and Implementation in accordance 
with EBU R 128’

[7]  EBU Tech Doc 3344 ‘Practical Guidelines for Distribution of Programmes in accordance 
with EBU R 128’